# Using randomly hex color, not the same value with a true generator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a function with vueJS for random hexadecimal color, but if I pick the output of my function, and I put the output on the generator of W3C for example (Link : [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hexadecimal.asp))

The function does not really work

So I hope to see the problem, because it's very disabling because I can't have a true value of Hex Color.

```js
let random = function () {

  let text = "";
  const possible = "ABCDEF0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *                               possible.length).toString(16));
     
  return '#' + text

}

const section = document.querySelector('section');
const title = document.querySelector('h1')

section.style.backgroundColor = random();
title.textContent = random();
```

```css
section {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<h1></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let random = function () {

  let text = "";
  const possible = "ABCDEF0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *                               possible.length).toString(16));
     
  return '#' + text

}

const section = document.querySelector('section');
const title = document.querySelector('h1')
var randomColor = random(); //get the color
section.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
title.textContent = randomColor;
```

```css
section {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<h1></h1>
```

Its because you are calling random function two time(`section.style` and `title.textContent`), call it once and store the value and use it, where you want.

Comment: @Jonathan `random()` function you are calling in your code two times , while setting in `section.style` and again in `title.textContent`

Comment: Yes Yes ! I realized after read your code and my code ! Thanks a lot

Comment: How to mark if it works ? 
I'm a new in StackOverflow !

Answer (score 2):

A simple

```
section.style.backgroundColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
```

is enough code

where `16777215 is #FFFFFF` in decimal and `toString(16)` creates a hexadecimal variant. Read more; [Number.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the random function twice, one for the text display, and once for the color square, so they're not mathching.

Here is a fix :

```js
let random = function () {

  let text = "";
  const possible = "ABCDEF0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *                               possible.length).toString(16));
     
  return '#' + text

}

const section = document.querySelector('section');
const title = document.querySelector('h1')

const color = random();
section.style.backgroundColor = color;
title.textContent = color;
```

```css
section {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: I understand Thanks a lot !